# Draw fitted Exgaussian density curve in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a set of estimated parameters for an Ex-gaussian curve (i.e. mu, sigma, tau).

Currently I'm creating a visualization of that distribution by simulating data based on those parameters and plotting them in ggplot.

I would rather create a visualization that is effectively a smooth fitted ex-gaussian curve - i.e. an estimated curve for data that presents with the parameters I've estimated. The goal is to not have curves with the same parameters appear differently.

Here is the current simulation approach I'm utilizing:

```
library(retimes)
library(ggplot2)

g <- rexgauss(1000,mu=1,sigma = 1,tau =1)
g <- as.data.frame(g); colnames(g) <- "obs"

ggplot(g) + geom_density(aes(x = obs), size=1, alpha=.4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stat_function` from `ggplot2`. It takes a function in `fun`, and parameters to pass to that function in `args`. It works well for situations like this where you want to compare a simulation to a calculated distribution, because the x values you supply to `aes` will be the ones automatically used in showing the function, without you having to do any work to match them up or calculate the range of x values in your simulation.

Here's an example with `retimes::rexgauss`. I also simplified your data frame creation, and put the parameters in a vector so you can use them in both the simulation and the calculated function.

My laptop is too slow to do all 1000 observations, so yours is probably smoother and closer to the calculated distribution than mine.

```r
library(ggplot2)

exgauss_params <- c(mu = 1, sigma = 1, tau = 1)
exgauss_sim <- data.frame(obs = retimes::rexgauss(n = 100, exgauss_params))

ggplot(exgauss_sim, aes(x = obs)) +
  geom_density(aes(color = "simulated")) +
  stat_function(aes(color = "calculated"), 
    fun = retimes::dexgauss, args = exgauss_params)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-05-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you! Works like a dream. I appreciate the detailed breakdown.